# Weather App Part for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, api

I need to implement weather widget on my SharePoint Online portal. Below are my basic requirement.

•   Each user of the portal tagged to specific location worldwide. Every time user logged into portal, by default user must be able to see current weather information of the location he/she tagged to.
We can provide the location detail (i.e. name of city) as a parameter wherever it’s needed.

•   We also want to provide a feature whereas user can go and search current weather condition by providing location detail (i.e. name of city) as search criteria.

I have explored all apps available on SharePoint market place. But none of them meeting my requirement. Could anyone please suggest if there's any app available out side the SharePoint market place which can meet my requirement?

As an another option, I am planning to create my own weather widget for SharePoint Online. I need suggestion which are the free weather apis available that can be used for commercial purpose.

Thanks,
Pratik.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to use darksky API to developed Weather app for O365

https://darksky.net/dev/

Also, you can get your user properties through this end point:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url     : "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties",
        type    : "GET",
        headers : {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        success : function (values) {
            Location = values.d;
            if (Location)
                // do something;
            return;
            },
        error:  function() {
                // do something;
            return;
            }
        });
```